# C++: Reading from stringstream

Tags: c++

I have an istringstream object with string of format
`STRING,INT,INT,INT`
eg. 
"name,20,30,40"
I want to read the values into variables of specific types such as std:string and int.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lazy way:

```
getline(stream, str, ',');
char c;
stream >> i1 >> c >> i2 >> c >> i3;
```

It is "lazy" because it does not handle format errors in any sensible way.

The smarter ways would be split on commas into a vector of strings (which can then be converted into integers as needed), or use a full-fledged parser, such as boost.spirit.

Comment: You can make this handle errors easily: `char c; if (getline(stream, str, ',') && stream >> i1 >> c && c == ',' && stream >> i2 >> c && c == ',' && stream >> i3) ...`